# Supervisor logrotate breaks on first logrotate occurrence

Tags: python, logging, supervisord, log-rotation

I'm trying to implement a supervisor application into my project. For now everything worked as expected, but I encountered a weird behavior with log rotate.

For testing purposes i have small python script which, while it's running, writes random string to log object which in turn writes it to stdout.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
import sys
import random
import string
import logging
from time import sleep

logger = logging.getLogger()
handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.info('Created global logging object')

while True:
    logger.debug(''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(random.randint(1,20))))
    sleep(0.00001)
```

This is my supervisord.conf file

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/tmp/supervisor.sock

[inet_http_server]
port=127.0.0.1:9001

[supervisord]
logfile=/home/usr/supervisor/supervisord.log
logfile_maxbytes=10MB
logfile_backups=10
loglevel=debug
pidfile=%(here)s/supervisor.pid

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock

[program:test_messagess]
command=/home/usr/python-scripts/testing/msgs/main.py
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)s
numprocs=50
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/trm/python-scripts/testing/msgs/main.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=10MB
stdout_logfile_backups=10
```

So here is what's happening:
Supervisord is started and script begins to work and main.log file is filling as expected. When main.log reaches size of about 10MB

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 usr usr 10,0M Tra  4 10:04 main.log
```

logs go insane, every log starts to have ~1MB (but this is different every time, it's not constant) of data and supervisor just starts rewriting everything

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 usr usr  962K Tra  4 10:04 main.log.8
-rw-r--r--. 1 usr usr  1,1M Tra  4 10:04 main.log.6
-rw-r--r--. 1 usr usr  1,2M Tra  4 10:04 main.log.5
-rw-r--r--. 1 usr usr  1,1M Tra  4 10:04 main.log.4
-rw-r--r--. 1 usr usr 1019K Tra  4 10:04 main.log.3
-rw-r--r--. 1 usr usr  954K Tra  4 10:04 main.log.2
-rw-r--r--. 1 usr usr  862K Tra  4 10:04 main.log.10
-rw-r--r--. 1 usr usr  987K Tra  4 10:04 main.log.1
-rw-r--r--. 1 usr usr  1,1M Tra  4 10:04 main.log.7
-rw-r--r--. 1 usr usr  904K Tra  4 10:04 main.log.9
-rw-r--r--. 1 usr usr  965K Tra  4 10:04 main.log
```

I tried some combinations (removing logging parameters from config file altogether leaving everything on DEFAULT, using only stderr instead of stdout) but nothing seems to work. Also, i tried printing messages directly to stdout -

```
print ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(random.randint(1,20))))
```

but same same problem occurs.

I'm using latest, 3.3.1 version of supervisor.

Ok, tried one more thing, it seems multiple process glitch out logrotate. I tried commenting out line "numprocess=50" so the proccess isn't forked and logs are working

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 usr usr 10,0M Tra  4 10:16 main.log.2
-rw-r--r--. 1 usr usr 10,0M Tra  4 10:17 main.log.1
-rw-r--r--. 1 usr usr 4,9M Tra  4 10:17 main.log
```

But this isn't really acceptable case, main use of supervisor is that is spawning multiple childs of same process... I also tried setting "numprocess=2" and again, logrotate is breaking.

Log rotation of supervisor log is working as expected (because it's not spawned multiple times).
Does anyone have any idea what is going on here?

Comment: what's happening is that each process you spawn will start writing to `main.log` (first process) and `main.log.N` (2nd onwards). Once they reach `stdout_logfile_maxbytes` they'll be pushed to `main.log.M` (being `M = N+numprocs` when `M < stdout_logfile_backups`). Give a try with 4 processes and 10 log files.

Comment: You're right, when i have that setup first the main.log goes to the limit (10M) and then main.log.1/2/3/4 are created, which are filling up at the same time. After that process is creating new files (5,6,7...) as needed.

Is this expected behavior of supervisor? I would say this is a bug and should be fixed.

Comment: I actually prefer it this way, otherwise you'll have output from different processes scrambled in the same file (but this is a minor issue anyway)